# How do I make this vbs script accept parameters when launching a file in the background?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, background

I have the following in a VBS file called "Launch.vbs":

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

I can call this from a batch file like this:

```
wscript.exe "Launch.vbs" "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe"
```

However, this does not allow me to pass parameters to it, for example:

```
wscript.exe "Launch.vbs" "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe" "Parameter"
wscript.exe "Launch.vbs" "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe" Parameter
```

In both of the above examples, the program does launch in the background, but does not receive any parameters given.

How can I modify the vbscript code to allow a parameter?

Comment: Try `wscript.exe "Launch.vbs" "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe Parameter"` you're only passing one argument to the `launch.vbs` script. You could pass two and adjust the `launch.vbs` script but this should work as well without having to adjust it.

Comment: It responds with `The system cannot find the file specified` if I do that @user692942.

How should I go about adjusting the launch.vbs script? I apologize, I mostly work with powershell so the vbscript world is alien to me.

Comment: The easiest way to work this out is what is the command line only version of the program you want to run and go from there. You could be hitting issues with paths with spaces, etc. It all depends on what the raw command you are trying to run (with parameters) is. Basically, if you try to run `ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe Parameter` from the command line without VBScript does it work, don't assume VBScript is the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is with `"""" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """"` in your launch script in effect you are asking it to run `"ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe Parameter"` when it should be `"ProgramIWantToStartInBackground" Parameter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version that processes all the possible arguments.

```
Dim strRun
strRun = ""
For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments
    strRun = strRun & """" & strArg & """ " 
Next
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run strRun, 0, False
```

Excute it as `wscript.exe Launch.vbs ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe Parameter1 Parameter 2 ... ParameterN`.

If there is space in the parameters or path, wrap that with `""` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of tackling this problem, but it boils down to understanding how programs run from the command prompt.

This line in `launch.vbs` is going to wrap any command passed in double-quotes which is fine for just the executable but causes issues when parameters are passed, as only the executable path should be wrapped in double-quotes to avoid issues with any spaces that might be in the path.

```vb
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Instead, you have two options.

1. Pass two arguments into `launch.vbs` and only wrap the first one in double quotes.

   ```vb
   CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """ " & 
   WScript.Arguments(1), 0, False
   ```

   Exeute using;

   ```
   wscript.exe "Launch.vbs" "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe" Parameter
   ```

   Executes as;

   ```
   "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground" Parameter
   ```
2. Remove the wrapping and apply to the argument passed in.

   ```vb
   CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run WScript.Arguments(0), 0, False
   ```

   Execute using;

   ```
   wscript.exe "Launch.vbs" ""ProgramIWantToStartInBackground.exe" Parameter"
   ```

   Executes as;

   ```
   "ProgramIWantToStartInBackground" Parameter
   ```